# Docker Compose stuck downloading or pulling fs layer

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the latest Docker for Mac installed, and I'm running into a problem where it appears that `docker-compose up` is stuck in a Downloading state for one of the containers:

```
± |master ✗| → docker-compose up --build
Pulling container (repo.io/company/container:prod)...
prod: Pulling from company/container
somehash: Already exists
somehash: Already exists
somehash: Already exists
somehash: Already exists
somehash: Pulling fs layer
somehash: Already exists
somehash: Already exists
somehash: Downloading [=================================================> ] 234.6 MB/239.3 MB
somehash: Download complete
somehash: Download complete
```

^^ this is literally what it looks like on my command line. Stopping and starting hasn't helped, it immediately outputs this same output.

I've tried to `rm` the container but I guess it doesn't yet exist, it returns the output `No stopped containers`. `--force-recreate` also gets stuck in the same place. And perhaps I'm not googling for the right terminology but I haven't found anything useful to try - any pointers?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I just needed to restart Docker.

Linux users can use `sudo service docker restart`.

Docker for Mac has a handy button for this in the Docker widget in the macOS toolbar:
[image: Docker for Macintosh in the macOS toolbar with restart button]

If you happen to be using Docker Toolkit try `docker-machine restart`.

Comment: It works! Almost pulled my hair on this. Thanks Hannele

Comment: Works for Windows too!

Answer (score 18):

I faced the same problem! Restarting the service didn't help, downloading again didn't help. It used to get stuck at random instances leaving me with no option but to kill the pull request.

One thing which worked for me was to download 1 file at a time. For Ubuntu users, you can use the following steps:

1. Stop the service:

   ```
   sudo service docker stop
   ```
2. Start docker with max concurrent download set as 1:

   ```
   sudo dockerd --max-concurrent-downloads 1
   ```
3. Download the required image:

   ```
   sudo docker pull <image_name>
   ```
4. Download images, after that stop the terminal and start the daemon again as it was earlier.

   ```
   sudo service docker start
   ```

Comment: Ah interesting, this is probably helpful if you have continually bad connections for some reason -- I think it was just a one-off for me.

Comment: Tweaking the max-concurrent-downloads settings seemed to help me. If you're working with Docker Desktop in Windows, you can modify the configuration in the Windows Dashboard UI under settings and Docker Engine. There's a JSON config there where you can add the max-concurrent-downloads option.

Comment: This worked for me, but I'm not sure why it works

Comment: Don't try this. It will shutdown docker daemon and a lot more story on starting it up! This almost gets the job done, but messes with some other stuff. bad solution.

Answer (score 13):

I had the similar situation this morning where my network suddenly went down and I was forced to power cycle the modern, while `docker-compose` was still in the middle of downloading stuff from docker hub.

Yes, bouncing the `docker daemon` process seems to resolve this.

For **Linux** users - do `sudo service docker restart` to fix it.

Comment: "Bouncing the `docker daemon`" - I'm using Docker for Mac, I guess this would be the same as hitting the restart button?

Comment: @Hannele - yes correct because when we restart our machine, essentially the operating system would kill/shutdown all running processes (including the docker daemon proc) before starting the OS again.

Comment: Ah apologies - I meant the restart button in the Docker widget - but I think this still applies :)

Comment: I faced similar issue, in my case local docker registry was not having enough space hence a layer was missed. After clearing space in docker-registry node and then tag and pushed. Then pulling success.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the Docker Preferences from its menu bar icon. Within there is a "bug" icon. Click on that and then "clean / Purge data"

Comment: Its called 'Troubleshoot" now

Answer (score 3):

I'm running OSX and restarting Docker for Mac didn't help. Neither did a full restart or upgrading VirtualBox. What did work was turning my wifi interface on and off every time it got stuck. I had to do this repeatedly, but it eventually downloaded the entire image.

Answer (score 3):

Directly download the necessary images using docker, e.g.

```
docker pull company/container
```

and then run

```
docker-compose up
```

again. Worked for me on MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible workaround.
I have my docker engine installed in a Ubuntu 18.04 Snap Environment.
I discovered searching in some forums that users relate this behaviors to limitation in the download bandwith.
So in the picture below you are going to watch that the components was stucked

[Part of the Downloads stucked and finally I cancelled the process CTRL + C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSpKs.png)

I added two parameters or flags in the configuration file that controls the docker daemon behavior: max-concurrent-downloads 1 and max-concurrent-uploads 1
In my case remember, i am working in a snap environment. This file is located in this directory: /var/lib/docker/current/config/daemon.json

REMEMBER TO STOP ALL DOCKER PROCESS BEFORE THE FILE MODIFICATION, AND CREATE BACKUP OF THE FILE

[Add the two lines in the picture. This is going to help you to limit the downloads to only one by one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtTGY.png)

This is the process that helped me to resolve this problem.
[Download Succesfull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THuFx.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in my VirtualBox when doing a docker pull on the image but it got stuck at a specific position and never moved from there. So, the issue was due to the network adapters in my VM. I was using NAT by default. When I switched it to "Bridged adapter", the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on docker for windows for a couple of days and when I tried to connect to the virtual machine (via Hyper-V Manager) the downloads started speeding along. I have no idea why but it worked for me...

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

- Completely remove docker
- Install docker again
- It should work now

I tried to restar docker, update docker, but didnt help

Comment: Did not work ether on my side. I'm trying to download a Docker Image from **Github Package Registry**. Download freezes since yesterday. Maybe it's a problem on their side, tried it with multiple internet connections.