# Docker pulling image is not successful, it stucks

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I used `docker-compose up` to pull the images. I have tried it more than 10 times, but still not yield the successful results. It always freezes at the Downloading process for some particular images (randomly each time).

It's happened like in this image all the time. The output from using `docker-compose up` commands:
[image: terminal screen shot]

```
tommiekub@dell3542:~/dev/freelance/sensebook$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.06.1-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.11
 Git commit:        e68fc7a215
 Built:             Fri Sep  7 11:26:59 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.1-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.11
  Git commit:       e68fc7a215
  Built:            Fri Sep  7 11:26:11 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Try restart Docker: `sudo service docker restart`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Compose stuck downloading or pulling fs layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087027/docker-compose-stuck-downloading-or-pulling-fs-layer)

Comment: I use Arch Linux, so I have already tried `sudo systemctl restart docker.service`, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I suffer from the same problem. My Docker version is 18.06.0-ce.
`sudo service docker restart` doesn't help for me

Comment: @AlfredUC What is the quality of your internet connection?

Comment: @Watchanan But I figured out something. This problem only occurs when using a gigabit switching hub.! with the non-gigabit switching hub, the Internet is slow, but the download is stable and works well. There seems to be a problem when the fast Internet environment.!??

Comment: @AlfredUC, for me, it works reversely as it can't complete the download at all when I am using poor internet connection. After I have tried to use the high-speed internet connection, it works perfectly as expected.

Comment: @Watchanan I have temporarily used a low speed switching hub again to resolve this issue. According to you, it is not a matter of speed but a network environment or equipment problem. Other internet usage works well, but there is a problem only in `docker pull`. So I would like the docker team to confirm.

Comment: I suspect that this is a problem with LAN card, and this is my LAN card information. `Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)`


What is your LAN card? (you can find out lan card information by `sudo lspci -v`)

Comment: I have used wireless all the time. `Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)`, this is my wireless interface information.