# Docker pull stuck after ubuntu upgrade

Tags: docker

OS: Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS (on an ESXi 6.7)
Docker : Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88

Since I upgraded my ubuntu server from 18.04 lts to 20.04 lts, I’m getting stuck when I want to pull an image :

```
$ docker pull alpine
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
ca3cd42a7c95: Downloading [===>                                               ]    204kB/2.812MB
```

It start to download and then get indefinitely stuck, my server has a good internet connection (2.5G) so that’s not the issue. I tested several images and I have the same issue.

I tried to restart the server and also tried to remove docker and reinstall it but still nothing to do. I don’t know what to do next, does any one has any idea ? I already lost 1 day searching different things without any solution…

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Compose stuck downloading or pulling fs layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087027/docker-compose-stuck-downloading-or-pulling-fs-layer)

Comment: Do you have enough disk space in your server? Try `df -h`. Also upgrading is not somehow recommended as it may sometimes result in unexpected issues. If you can, I recommend reinstalling VM machine with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @Clément Baconnier - I've already tried every solution here but still not working, that's why why I'm opening my topic, thanks anyway.

Comment: @Saeed - Yes I have enough disk space, I'm only using 50%. It would be a shame to reinstall the entire VM just because docker pull isn't working, there must be a reason for this.

Comment: Perhaps you will find a more usefull answer here? https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2083

Comment: @Clément Baconnier - I've already checked this too. Like I said, I searched for almost 1 day, most of the people having this issue are on windows or mac and restarting docker resolve the problem for most of them. That's why I'm here.

Comment: *I searched for almost 1 day* doesn't help us to understand what you already tried or didn't. If you don't want your question be flagged as duplicate, not meeting stackoverflow guideline or don't want people that tries to help you giving the same things you already tried, please, be more specific.

Comment: Clément Baconnier - Like I said in the topic : "I tried to restart the server and also tried to remove docker and reinstall it but still nothing to do". And I'm on ubuntu, every other topic or issue I found was not on linux or was solved by restarting/reinstalling. My server have a good internet connection and my containers too. That's all I guess, I have no more useful information to share.